# Overuse of public variables to speak between two ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am just starting to get into apple AVFoundation package to create an app using the camera. I have noticed that in my code I am using a fair amount of public variables to communicate with the apple CameraViewController and my CameraVC that controlls the actual view. For example:

```
public var _photoButton: UIButton!

public var _imageTaken: UIImageView!

public var _sendBtn: UIButton!

public var _dismissBtn: UIButton!

public var _videoDismissBtn: UIButton!

public var _videoSendBtn: UIButton!

public var photoData: Dictionary<String, Data>!
```

I am using these variables to connect with buttons I have on my UI that perform special tasks, aswell as to pass image/video data over to my other viewcontroller.  (dismiss the current image/video, send the current image/video to a server). I am trying to hold my self to using best practices but I couldn't think of a better solution. What affect would using these public variables have on the performance of my app, and if possbible, how can I write this better?

Example: CameraVC (not apples CameraViewController)

```
   @IBAction func sendBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "FriendsVC", sender: ["snapshotData": photoData.removeValue(forKey: "photoData")])
    self.view.insertSubview(previewView, aboveSubview: imageTaken)
    self.sendBtn.isHidden = true
    self.sendBtn.isEnabled = false
    self.dismissBtn.isEnabled = false
    self.dismissBtn.isHidden = true
}

   @IBAction func dismissBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.insertSubview(previewView, aboveSubview: imageTaken)
    self.sendBtn.isHidden = true
    self.sendBtn.isEnabled = false
    self.dismissBtn.isEnabled = false
    self.dismissBtn.isHidden = true
    self.photoData = nil
    return
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code where you are trying to pass these variables? Actually these can be kept private. And wrapper methods can be provided to modify them.

Comment: sure, here is an example

Answer (score 0):

The fact that these properties are public does not affect performance. It is more relevant in methods, when you set `private` instead of `public` and this way compiler could ascertain that this method is `final`.

Another point for performance - if you send data to server ,as you mentioned you do, it is highly recommended to do this in background queue asynchronously (GCD) if you haven't already done it.

As for implementing otherwise - need to see whole picture. From what I see here, you send a value from your dictionay along with the segue and enbaling/disabling buttons and there's nothing wrong with that. As long as you don't clone/send to server large portion of picture/video data on the main thread, it's ok.

Last tip - don't need always the performSegue - if you want to pass data to the next ViewController and invoke it - you can use the Navigation Controller (your initial View Controller needs to be embedded in a Navigation Controller of course) Something like:

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as? NextViewController{
if let navigator = self.navigationController{
    vc.someProperty = someDataToPass

    navigator.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am parsing the data in a model before it goes off to my firebase storage.Thank you for your reply and I will play with the navigation controller to see how it works